# fluentd file plugin \ how to keep only latest X files?

Tags: docker, fluentd

I'm using fluentd file plugin. is there a way to configure it to keep only last X files (for example last 10 files)? I didn't find it in the documentation.

second and less important question - how can I set the file name with index

myApp_1.log

myApp_2.log

.
.

myApp_10.log

my fluent.conf is:

```
# Receive events from 24224/tcp
# This is used by log forwarding and the fluent-cat command
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  remove_keys source,container_id,container_name
</filter>

<match tagger*>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/log/tagger/tagger 
    append true
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
    output_time false
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information? How is this related to Docker? Are you using the fluentd `out_file` plugin?

Comment: thanks - yep - I'm doing --log-driver=fluentd, and local fluentd docker gets the records. the output I'm using out_file plugin. is it possible out_file doesn't support this trivial option?

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. how can anyone use out_file plugin without purging option? the disc will explode..

Comment: It sounds like rotation is left to an external component (such as logrotate). I know it isn't really helpful. But it seems like the answer is "logrotation isn't possible in fluentd".